# Exporting data from query results

Tags: user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014, export-to-csv

I am using MS SQL server 2014.
I have a table-valued function
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Resultsaddresssearch](@addressLine nvarchar, @locality nvarchar, @adminDistrict nvarchar, @postalCode nvarchar, @countryRegion nvarchar)
RETURNS  TABLE (
    [Name] nvarchar NULL,
    [Point] [geography] NULL,
    [BoundingBox] [geography] NULL
) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [xtest2].[addresssearch.UserDefinedFunctions].[GeocodeTVF]`

that I use this query 
`SELECT * FROM dbo.Resultsaddresssearch('999 NE 10th%', '', '', '', 'USA');`

The results I wish to export to a premaded csv that is addy,csv. When I used the export manager, I selected the sql native client 11 as source. Then select Flat File as destination. I enter the query from above and hit next and I get this error:

```
      - Column "Point": Source data type "204" was not found in the data type mapping file.
      - Column "BoundingBox": Source data type "204" was not found in the data type mapping file.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not what I what but creating an sql query 
`Insert into [dbo].[ConversionofGeotest2] 
Select * from Geotest2 ('62 NE 10th Ave', '', '', '97211', 'US');`